# How to get a device identifier using Phonegap

Tags: cordova, key, device, identifier

I need to get any number, serial, key or whatever to identify every device where my phonegap app is running, I think **uuid** also changes when the app updates so it wouldn't work for me.

The scenario here is that the user can synchronize data from the app, so I need to know which device has synchronized and which has not, or if it needs to update new data that maybe others devices have already done, etc

any ideas?

Comment: I think I have figured out a way to make this do what you want with a couple caveats, but it will survive multiple app installations at least on iOS.  What platforms are the most important for the purposes of this discussion?

Comment: @r3wt Have you already checked this cordova plugin? https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID

Comment: @r3wt Do you need a solution for which kind of platforms (Android, iOS, ...)?

Comment: @beaver your answer does the trick i think. thanks man.

Comment: @r3wt I added the answer, please vote it if you believe and it satisfies your requirements

Answer (score 10):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
    element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                        'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
}

</script>
```

After getting the device info you can apply your logic to validation.

Refer: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

Comment: As I said in my post, the uuid changes when the app updates, and the other information can be easily repeated so that wouldn't work for what I need

Comment: where does the `device object` came from?

Comment: Which one you refer to?

Comment: which ı add  phonegap plugin?

Answer (score 9):

I suggest to use this PhoneGap/Cordova plugin:

https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID

As declared in the documentation

> it remains the same after app uninstall.

Comment: On iOS, the plugin merely generates a unique UUID and stores it in the keychain for the user. If that entry gets deleted, the next one will be different.

Answer (score 3):

When a user first installs the app you could make an API call to get a unique ID from the system you are using to sync data and then you could store that ID in a localStorage variable, or to a database table. Then you refer to that ID stored on the device when making calls.

Comment: yea I thought of that, but what if the users uninstall the app? that is a pain in the ass, I first thought about using the imei number but wouldn't work on tablets

Comment: Yeah, may need to consider a signup in that case. Then you can also cover the instance of a user getting a new device, or if they need to RMA their device for the same device.