# How get Device uuid on PHONEGAP

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, device

I see any examples of this, but all of than use the "device ready", I really need to use this event or I can get the device uuid out of this event?

When I tested this on my browser  I got the gap of device uuid, but on device this don't show me anything.

Anyone Can show me an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a device identifier using Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359655/how-to-get-a-device-identifier-using-phonegap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this [plugin cordova device](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) which is able to get the device uuid. 
As always plugins can only be used after the device ready event was fired.

Example:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device.uuid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the repply and explanation

Answer (score 2):

Install the Device plugin as explained here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

Then in your Javascript call `device.uuid`.

Comment: Thanks for the repply and explanation

Comment: @MarcosHenrique happy to help!