# IONIC APP- get device id for post service($http.post)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get the device id getUUID at the time of app login along with username and password. Is the right way to get device id and post it to the server for login.

controller.js

```
      .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http,$rootScope,$window,$location,$cordovaDevice) {
         $scope.login = function () {
                var data ={

                  username : $scope.username,
                  password : $scope.password
                };
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
               $http.post('login', data, config)
              .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  // $scope.DataResponse = data;
                  $location.path('#/tab/new-order');
              })
              .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                  $window.alert("username or password incorrect");
              });
                  console.log(device.cordova);
               }

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }
    };

  })
```

html code

```
  <form action="" class="ki-login-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="form-group username">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" id="identity" placeholder="Your Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group pin">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" value="" id="identity" placeholder="Your Pin">
            </div>
            <a type="submit" class="btns" ng-click='login()' >Login</a>
    </form>
```

After login it has to be directed to a page href="#/tab/new-order" in the ionic tab

Comment: I have added it above, please check once

Comment: yes u can get the uuid after the device ready..and u can post it..whats ur question actually?

Comment: Yes I tried above method to get device id and then post it to a server but I am getting this error now 
 $ is not defined
    at ChildScope.$scope.login

Comment: i wrote an answer..see if it works..why are u using $.param..it seems to be jquery function, which i hope you are not using..and u should not use as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a device identifier using Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359655/how-to-get-a-device-identifier-using-phonegap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dependency injection $location in controller function like following -

```
 .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope,$window,$location) {
// Your code
});
```

Solution for your added comment -

Use following - 
Add device plugin : `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device`

In your controller :

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDevice) { 
    var uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID(); 
});
```

Comment: $ is not defined
    at ChildScope.$scope.login 
Getting above error

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined
    at controllers.js:47
    at Object.ready (ionic.bundle.js:2140)
    at ChildScope.$scope.login (controllers.js:38)

Comment: Update with the change above, you instructed

Comment: ReferenceError: device is not defined
    at Object.getUUID When trying from browser

Comment: As we are using plugin, it will not work on browser. It will work on device

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
var data = $.param({

              username : $scope.username,
              password : $scope.password,


   });
```

to

```
var data = {

              username : $scope.username,
              password : $scope.password,


   };
```

UPDATE -

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device.cordova);
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined 
On editing above syntax

Comment: ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
            $http.post('login', data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // $scope.DataResponse = data;
                $location.path('#/tab/new-order');
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $window.alert("username or password incorrect");
            });
            console.log( window.device.uuid );
          });

Comment: Same uuid error after editing- check the code in the question. I've updated it

Comment: u r still using $.param!! u shdnt do that

Comment: I have removed them in my code, I'll update here as well.

Comment: instead of ionic platform ready event...do ur post on deviceready event ...see update

Comment: Do I need to include this also?
element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +

                        'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +

                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359655/how-to-get-a-device-identifier-using-phonegap

Comment: glad it worked..no u need not add this code..dont forget to upvote the answer ;)

Comment: :)  thanks all I'm not getting any error now. but this has to be there right- var uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();