# Account Activation with Fingerprint

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, uniqueidentifier, fingerprint

**Story**

I am developing an app that will be used from desktop and mobile browser (NodeJS, JS, HTML, CSS). I am also planning to wrap it with phonegap or react native to make it a downloadable/installable mobile app later.

Users can sign up with `username` and `password`. But the user account will be activated only after user's `thumb fingerprint` validation. This is to avoid duplicate/ghost accounts bring created.

**Note**

Fingerprints are not good passwords. So I am only planning to use them to activate account. After an account is activated users will login using usual username and password.

> **Queries**
>
> 1. How to get user's `thumb fingerprint` or a `unique token` that represents fingerprint in HTML, JS, CSS?
> 2. Is there anything else that will stop duplicate/ghost account other than fingerprint?

Comment: Here's a question with a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359655/how-to-get-a-device-identifier-using-phonegap

Comment: No. That identifies unique device(or browser fingerprint). I want to identify unique person. A person can own many devices.